# big dataset, receiving "Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow" when using unstack()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, overflow, int32

I tried `pivot` and `groupby + unstack`, both gave me errors. 
the error says

> "Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow".

I tried to downgrade `pandas` to `0.21` but its not compatible with `python 3.7`, so is there any solutions?

```py
user_by_movie=  user_items.groupby(['user_id', 'movie_id'])['rating'].min().unstack()
```

Answer (score -2):

## Answer

This should work, let me know.

`user_by_movie=  user_items.groupby(['user_id', 'movie_id'])['rating'].min().to_frame()`